# How to access for loop index in a closure typescript?

Tags: typescript, ionic2, closures

I want to push this.companies[i] in to this.companyForFlyers but as this is async I always get the wrong value in variable i (i is always -1 when I debug the code). How to I fix this?

```
else if (category == "Favorite") {
  for (var i = this.companies.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    this.storage.get(this.companies[i].CompanyName).then(val => {
      if (val == "true"){
        this.companyForFlyers.push(this.companies[i])
      }
    });
  }
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that variables declared with `var` are function scoped, so subsequent changes made by  the loop will be reflected in the value of `i` captured by the loop. Use `let` to create a block scoped variable instead.

```
for (let i = this.companies.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    this.storage.get(this.companies[i].CompanyName).then(val => {
      if (val == "true"){
        this.companyForFlyers.push(this.companies[i])
      }
    });
}
```